# Asking for an algorithm in 3-connected planar graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Good day.

Does somebody knows an algorithm to obtain any 3-connected planar graph on n vertices from one on n-2 vertices by subdividing two edges in the
boundary of a face and joining the resulting new vertices by an edge subdividing
the face?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [Tutte's Wheel Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TuttesWheelTheorem.html).  Every polyhedral graph can be derived from a wheel graph via repeated graph contraction and edge splitting.

Answer (score 0):

You might also be interested in "Fast generation of planar graphs" by G Brinkmann and BD McKay which explains how to (quickly!) generate non-isomorphic planar graphs of which 3-connected graphs are a subset.

The problem with the naïve expansion algorithm is that it will generate isomorphic graphs, which becomes worse the larger the graph. Techniques like Brinkmann and McKay's will reject expansions that are not canonical.

Other papers by these authors are interesting for the general approach:

https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&q=gunnar+brinkman&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=